# Change Visibility of AWS Application Load Balancer to Internal Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I had created an Application Load Balancer and it was set as public. I have bifurcated certain things and want to convert it to an internal load balancer so that it is exposed only to the VPC resources. But when I change the visibility option from 'public' to 'internal', I get this error -

```
Updating Load Balancer listener named: 
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxx:listener/app/awseb-AWSEB-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx failed Reason: 
The following target groups cannot be associated with more than one load balancer:
 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:targetgroup/awseb-AWSEB-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
(Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: TargetGroupAssociationLimit)
```

Comment: Try to localize the issue. For example create new internal LB instead of updating existing one, then try to move target groups to new LB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem recently. To fix it, I had to disable to rule listener. Afterward, I was able to set it from public to internal.

Comment: I have no rule listeners to disable

Answer (score 0):

Just disabling the listener helped me, I guess it cannot bind on the same port while changing visibility type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).